# Can you modify a csproj to be an empty utility project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, csproj

I would like to create a .csproj for a utility project.  This project has no binary output, and is just used to group a bunch of other projects into a common dependency.

I am already using .csproj inheritance and custom targets so I am very comfortable with hacking the files and having no GUI support.  Does anyone have a working "empty .csproj that can be used to build only its dependencies?

I don't want people to have to install any workload other than C# Desktop.  That's why I am not using a normal C++ utility project, for example.  I could obviously just build something that I don't actually distribute, but it seemed like there should be a cleaner solution.

Concretely, to address all the people asking me why:

- I have one DLL that's basically a core SDK
- I have a bunch of DLLs that are plugins or modules on that SDK
- I have a few executables, each of which doesn't know the plugins exist but of course I want them all built first when I do a "Run" on the executable

So I group all the plugins under "All plugins", plugins each require and link the SDK, and each executable just depends on "All plugins" without linking.  Obviously it links the SDK.  Works great.  Just that the "All plugins" project is a DLL I throw away :) and that seems ugly.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to reverse engineer a Visual Studio solution rather than a project.

Comment: Or perhaps you're defining a metapackage? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/packages#metapackages (It doesn't sound like it's really a C# project.)

Comment: May be it is better to use the command line compiler than a project file.  Give a lot more options.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/command-line-building-with-csc-exe

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, but I really just want to bundle up dependencies in the IDE build.

Comment: edited description to clarify specific case of what I am trying to do so and why

Comment: and yes Jon Skeet, it is exactly a metapackage.  Only the contributors to this project don't work with packages at all and are used to just clicking buttons in the IDE.  So I am trying to do this without converting everything over.  Maybe some day the SDK portion will be a package like it should be.